# Youtube iFrame in Android WebView unrecognized profile

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, youtube

I am trying to create a Youtube player using a WebView instead of the Youtube API for android which I find very limiting.

I have tried using HTML and JavaScript to play the video on a iFrame as instructed by Google: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Mainly using this HTML code and load it to the WebView:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have therefore just started putting a regular iFrame and the video is actually loaded and showing with this kind of code:
`webview.loadData("<body><iframe id=\"iframe\" src=" + url + " height=\"300\"\n" </iframe></body>", "text/html","utf-8");`
The problem is that I can autoplay the video, as well as having absolutely no control over the player.
I have tried adding "autoplay=1" with all its possible variations to autoplay. And the first method using the proper div method and javascript as instructed by google results in having absolutely nothing showing, with these log messages:

```
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/alac
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/dsd
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx311
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/divx4
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
```

I still get these messages when using the iFrame alone, but the video loads and I can click on it and it plays as expected.

If anyone can shed any light on this problem I have, ideally how to control the video using the proper "Google" way, or at least help me autoplay it using the other method.

P.S: I have enabled JS, hardware acceleration, set chrome as the web browser, checked the permissions. As I have said, I get the video to play after physically clicking on it, but it's just user driven and I have no control over it programmatically.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?